# Can't get around Pandas Series SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, chained-assignment

I'd like to fetch a `Series` and make changes to it, which I'd like reflected in the `DataFrame` later on. However I can't understand how to do it without the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Is this a false positive or am I doing something wrong?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=list('abc'))
df['d'] = df['a'].diff()
d = df.loc[:, 'd']
d.loc[d>0] *= 3
```

I've read the docs (and *yes*, I did read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) before asking but it only deals with DataFrames and not with Series), but isn't able to work out how to fix this. I would prefer not to disable the warning, as I have code where I don't want to make this type of mistake inadvertently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: FYI I created a tag, [tag:chained-assignment] for this subject.  Perhaps it should be renamed to just SettingWithCopyWarning because chained assignment might have a broader programming context/scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to fetch a Series and make changes to it, which I'd like
>   reflected in the DataFrame later on.

In this case, you should temporarily disable this warning and proceed as you are now.  Using `.copy()` will mean your original `df` will be unmoidified by changes to `d`.

```
with pd.option_context('mode.chained_assignment', None):
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=list('abc'))
    df['d'] = df['a'].diff()
    d = df.loc[:, 'd']
    d.loc[d>0] *= 3

# Code you run outside of `with` will maintain your original setting:
# pd.get_option('chained_assignment')
```

`option_context` is a context manager, meaning it can be used with [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), and the option only applies to code within the block.

Read more: pandas > [Getting & Setting Options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#getting-and-setting-options)

Comment: Temporary disabling is a great suggestion, if there is no 'real' solution, I'll stick with this!

Comment: Over time I cant disagree to this solution. Im such an amateur

Comment: @Bharath Not at all man.  It's a tricky topic because in a minority of cases, it's a warning that actually should be ignored.